# converting object to datetime without time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have dataframe that looks like below:

```
         Date      Region     Data
   0   200201        A        8.8
   1   200201        B        14.3
                    ...     
1545   202005        C        7.3
1546   202005        D        131
```

I wanted to convert the Date column(data type: object) to DateTime index without time. yyyymm or yyyymmdd or yyyy-mm-dd all of these don't matter as long as I can erase the time part.

I've searched stackoverflow and tried these codes

```
# (1) 
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format = "%Y%m", errors = "coerce", uts = False)
# (2)
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format = "%Y%m")
df["Date"] = df["Date"].dt.normalize()
# (3)
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format = "%Y%m")
df["Date"] = df["Date"].dt.date
```

For (1) and (2), I get ["Date"] with time like yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.

For (3), I do get ["Date"] as yyyymm but the dtype is object.

I can't use date range because same date is repeated for some time.

Will there be any way to convert yyyymm[object] to yyyymmdd[datetime] in python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's generally better if you insert the output of your program as text into your question instead of linking screenshots. For more information check out the [how to ask page.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In my system the commands are working correctly

Comment: @a.deshpande012 Okay, thanks for your tips!

Comment: @bigbounty I think something's wrong with my spyder program. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a display configuration issue on how your DataFrames are showing in your editor. The simplest way to get the data in the right format is:

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y%m')
```

Below are the results from [repl.it](https://repl.it/@WilliamGriffin1/ComplexVapidSimulation#main.py) with your DataFrame and this code. The date is properly formatted without the time component, and it has the proper dtype.

```
        Date Region  Data
0 2002-01-01      A   8.8

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   Date    1 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   Region  1 non-null      object        
 2   Data    1 non-null      float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 152.0+ bytes
```

You can also try a more convoluted way of going from datetime to date string and back to datetime.

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y%m').dt.date
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

The final display and dtypes are the same.

```
        Date Region  Data
0 2002-01-01      A   8.8

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   Date    1 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   Region  1 non-null      object        
 2   Data    1 non-null      float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 152.0+ bytes
```

Comment: Thanks, I think something's wrong with my spyder. I tried the same code in colab and it shows in yyyy-mm-dd format. Thank you so much for your help and great explanation. I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The Date column in the question has the format YYYYMM (but no days).  The function `pd.to_datetime()` implicitly sets the day to 1.

The function `pd.Period()` converts dates in the format YYYYMM to pandas periods.  Note that df['Date'] can be strings or 6-digit integers.

```
df['Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.Period(x, freq='M'))

0    2002-01
1    2002-01
2    2020-05
3    2020-05
Name: Date, dtype: period[M]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it!